# What does risk assessment summary table for C rules mean?

Tags: c

As per CERT C Coding Standard, every single rule is accompanied with a risk assessment summary table.

For example:

Rule 02. Declarations and Initialization (DCL)

DCL31-C. Declare identifiers before using them

Risk Assessment Summary

Rule        Severity    Likelihood    Remediation  Cost    Priority     Level

DCL31-C      Low       Unlikely          Low                P3           L3

What message does the risk assessment summary table convey the programmer, how does one interpret it? What are the above mentioned terms? What do they mean?

Comment: For that rule, the problem identified is low severity (it won’t often have a big impact), it is unlikely to occur?, it doesn’t cost much to fix it, so the overall ranking is L3.  I forget how the alphanumeric grades work but I think L3 is low and level 3 (of 9?) compared with medium or high, each with levels 1..9 or thereabouts.

Comment: It should all be explained on the website and/or in your PDF copy.

Comment: See [Risk Assessment](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/How+this+Coding+Standard+is+Organized#HowthisCodingStandardisOrganized-RiskAssessment) under 'How this Coding Standard is Organized".

Answer (score 0):

As per the [introduction to the SEI CERT coding standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/How+this+Coding+Standard+is+Organized#HowthisCodingStandardisOrganized-RiskAssessment), the risk assessment is calculated as the product of the severity, likelihood, and remediation cost.

Each of these carry the values `1` through `3`, as follows:

```
                         1             2            3
+------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
| Severity         | Low        | Medium       | High      |
+------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
| Likelihood       | Unlikely   | Probable     | Likely    |
+------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
| Remediation cost | High (m/m) | Medium (a/m) | Low (a/a) |
+------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

The `m` and `a` items in the final line dictate the detection and correction requirements for dealing with the rule (`m` means manual, `a` means automatic). So we have a table that has high numbers for increasing severity and likelihood and decreasing effort in remediation.

The resultant product gives a priority of `1` through `27` though only certain values in that range are possible (for example, there's no way to multiply the number together to get `7`).

That product (the priority) is then turned into a level as follows:

Priority `1` through `4` are level `3` - these are toward the low severity, unlikely and hard-to-remediate end of the scale.

Priority `6`, `8` and `9` are level `2` - these are in the middle in terms of severity, likelihood and remediation effort.

Priority `12`, `18` and `27` are level `1` - these tend toward high severity, likely problems which are easier to fix.

The reason it's done this way is so that, if you tackle the issues in decreasing level order, you'll get the best "bang per buck" for your efforts.